# Android repository pattern for firestore

Tags: android, firebase, concurrency, repository-pattern, google-cloud-firestore

To have a better separation of concerns I'd like to implement a repository which handles all the firestore interaction.

Currently, my code looks like this:

UserRepository:

```
public class UserRepository {

    private static final String TAG = "UserRepository";

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection("users");

    public Task<DocumentSnapshot> get(String email) {
        DocumentReference docRef = usersRef.document(email); // Users are referenced by email
        Log.d(TAG, "Checking DocumentReference exists for: " + email);
        return docRef.get();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
                final UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();

                userRepository.get(currentUser.getEmail()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot got");
                        // Do something with user
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Could not get DocumentReference", e);
                    }
                });
```

User is a POJO

What I would like to achieve is a Repository which instead of Task returns Task somewhat like this:

```
public Task<User> get(String email) {
    DocumentReference docRef = usersRef.document(email);
    /* Convert and return task? */
}
```

Which then could be used like usual, attaching a listener in the MainActivity. I'm afraid I am somewhat lacking skill in concurrency but I feel like this should be possible without having to synchronize. Could you give me a hint on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the solution was pretty simple, using a Continuation. I was not sure if task-chaining was what I was actually looking for but it seems like a good solution. The get method now looks like this:

```
public Task<User> get(String email) {
    DocumentReference docRef = getDocumentReference(email);

    return docRef.get().continueWith(new Continuation<DocumentSnapshot, User>() {
        @Override
        public User then(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            return task.getResult().toObject(User.class);
        }
    });
}
```

Edit:
Per request I created a gist containing my implementation:
[Firestore Repository Gist](https://gist.github.com/NiPfi/f00dc0f8178ef907202ed1046ced2746)

Comment: Do you have rest of the code publicly available? I'd love to see how you went about implementing Firestore under the repository pattern.

Comment: @NajmSheikh I edited my answer to include a gist of my implementation

Comment: That was quite helpful! Thank you!